# Windows Native codes for forward and backward

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, mouse, native-methods

I'm a WPF developer, i have tecknet wireless mouse with me, and it have two extra buttons.

when i click on them it navigates to-fro from history in browser.

Interestingly, it also works on Windows Explorer, Microsoft Outlook and VisualStudio. Means i can go to previously visited files or location by one button and can come to current by another button.

I tried to find, how they implement this one in their driver, so far no luck. If you guys know about this, share the information. I will use it in my next application.

Thanks,